# Accessing imageview of different layout from fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, imageview

I want Image2 with id R.id.guggu_media2 to be visible on scrolling and Image with id R.id.guggu_media to be invisible on scrolling.Both Image and Image2  are part of GugguAdapter.java which has layout item_pager_image.xml.My HomeFragment.java has different layout and i want to access the imageview of different layout.Is it possible?Also as per my project both Image and Image2 cannot be declared outside _getViewForAudioMedia() inside GugguAdapter.java.Through _getViewForAudioMedia() method i am playing audio and i am pausing the audio if user scrolls..But i also want imagebutton to change from playing(R.id.guggu_media) to paused(R.id.guggu_media2) on scrollling..

HomeFragment.java

```
  public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements OnRefreshListener {
               @Override
                public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
             homeFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_guggu_moments, container, false);
              public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {


                    }

                    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {


                       GugguApplication.getInstance().cleanUp(mVisulizerView);



                    }
                });
         return homeFragmentView;
            }
```

GugguAdapter.java

```
    public void _getViewForAudioMedia(int position,final GugguMoment lMoment, View convertView)
    {
final VisualizerView     lVisualizerView = (VisualizerView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.visualizerView);
  final ImageView Image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.guggu_media);
        final ImageView Image2 = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.guggu_media2);


        if (!mIsAudioPlaying) {

            Image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Image2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        else
        {
            Image2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Image.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

            convertView.findViewById(R.id.guggu_image).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            convertView.findViewById(R.id.guggu_video).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            final ProgressBar lAudioProgressBar = (ProgressBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.guggu_video_progress);
            lAudioProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            Image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view)
                {
                    lVisualizerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    GugguApplication.getInstance().cleanUp(lVisualizerView);
                    GugguApplication.getInstance().initTunnelPlayerWorkaround(mCtxt);
                    GugguApplication.getInstance().init(mCtxt, lMoment.getGugguMediaLoc(), lVisualizerView, lAudioProgressBar);
                    Image.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                   Image2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mIsAudioPlaying = true;

                }

            });
        Image2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                Image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Image2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                GugguApplication.getInstance().cleanUp(lVisualizerView);
            }

        });
            lVisualizerView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if (mIsAudioPlaying)
                    {
                        Image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        Image2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        GugguApplication.getInstance().cleanUp(lVisualizerView);
                    }
                }

            });
        }
```

Comment: Could not understand your question. Try rephrasing it. Also avoid posting unrelated code to the question, use generic names and add comments to clarify the flow and intent.

Comment: @Alex check out my updated question.. i want Image2 with id R.id.guggu_media2 to be visible on scrolling and Image with id R.id.guggu_media to be invisible on scrolling..for that i have to put the code inside onScrollStateChanged() which is declared inside HomeFragment.java whose layout is R.layout.fragment_guggu_moments..but i want to access imageView s of different layout as required per my project..